# Replacing a Custom DoEvents-Function

Tags: c#, async-await, vb6-migration

I've been recently introduced to a project that uses WPF to visualize some work. The application uses some custom windows to display a popup window. There is a bug in the application where this custom popup window will not go away when clicking "OK", or rather it seems to re-appear immediately.

From what I can tell, the issue might be due to a custom `DoEvents` function based on the infamous `DoEvents` in VB6. I'm having trouble implementing a better solution for this, because this `DoEvents` locks the user into the custom popup window, but does not block the main thread and my attempt at an async solution failed.

This is the `DoEvents` implementation:

```
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
public static void DoEvents()
{
    DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrame), frame);
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);

    Thread.Sleep(10);
}

public static object ExitFrame(object f)
{
    ((DispatcherFrame)f).Continue = false;
    return null;
}
```

And this is the function that uses it (simplified):

```
public static DialogResult Show(string view, string caption)
{
    if (dialogIsOpen)
        return DialogResult.Cancel;
    dialogIsOpen = true;

    // Instantiates the view and sets it in the region.
    MyApplication.OpenView(view, caption);

    object? result = default;
    while ((result = MyApplication.GetValue("MyResult") == null)
        MyApplication.DoEvents();

    // Clears the region.
    MyApplication.ResetView();

    dialogIsOpen = false;
    return result is DialogResult ? (DialogResult)result : DialogResult.Cancel;
}
```

The instantiated popup view will write the value "MyResult", when the user confirms the popup.

I tried implementing the same logic using `Task`, but it ended up freezing my application (and not showing the popup at all).

```
public static DialogResult Show(string view, string caption)
{
    if (dialogIsOpen)
        return DialogResult.Cancel;
    dialogIsOpen = true;

    // Instantiates the view and sets it in the region.
    MyApplication.OpenView(view, caption);

    var task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        object? result = default;
        while ((result = MyApplication.GetValue("MyResult") == null)
            await Task.Delay(10);
        return result;
    });
    object? result = task.Result;

    // Clears the region.
    MyApplication.ResetView();

    dialogIsOpen = false;
    return result is DialogResult ? (DialogResult)result : DialogResult.Cancel;
}
```

I think the problem is that the main thread waits for the async code to finish (and blocks user input). I lack some multitasking experience so I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Do you really _need_ the window to be custom? Could it just be replaced by something "oridinary"?

Comment: @Fildor yes, the window displays UI controls that can't be displayed as text

Comment: So? You still do not need such an abomination to display a graphical representation of data. Relying on the value of a global variable alone is a big bright red flag, here.

Comment: ^^ That being said: I believe you are waisting your time trying to fix this. Scrap it and do it right. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/may/xaml-custom-xaml-controls

Comment: in your attempt- the Task.Run(...) the task is being waited on (blocking) the main thread because of the "task.Result" line. instead you can use ContinueWith and put the rest of code inside

Comment: ^^ No. Don't do that. If you go async, go all the way. And that doesn't seem to be an option, here. The one solution, I could imagine would work, would be to use a [TaskCompletionSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=net-7.0) but that would still mean you needed to make `Show` an `async Task`.

Comment: But in fact, a _Dialog_ (aka Modal in other contexts) is _supposed_ to be blocking, because you need the result before you can continue. By _not_ implementing this the standard WPF-way, your predecessors digged your grave. I am 100% confident, your time is much better spent in fixing the underlying issue ( not having created a proper WPF Dialog ) than patching the fuse of that timebomb.

Comment: @Fildor I think you're right. Just so we're on the same page: the WPF way would be to create a proper WPF dialog, show it to the user and pass the result to a callback (or event handler) when the dialog closes?

Comment: Something like that, yes. Maybe read some tutorial on WPF custom dialogs, so you get the pitfalls and stuff. It should be extensively documented. Just be careful what is relevant to your "kind" of WPF (.NET (Core+) vs .Net Framework)

Comment: Was there some requirement that prevented using a dialog in the first place? Like, is stuff supposed to be live updating in the background window while the "dialog" is visible?

Comment: @StayOnTarget yes, the dialog is part of a region and it's displayed in the foreground of that region. The user is allowed to switch the content of the background using controls outside of that region, but the dialog should remain in the foreground

Answer (score 2):

The usage of DoEvents (maybe in the first place) was done to avoid using proper multi-threading.

The right solution would be using callbacks, or async functions, or to subscribe to events.

for example, instead of creating a loop which is waiting for some value to be filled-
you can create an event and raise it when fulfilled.

this way your code won't be "waiting" and holding the thread blocked